# Trying to set wake timer, date is confusing

Tags: 14.04, server, suspend, wakeup

I'm trying to set wake timer with this command

```
sudo rtcwake -m no -l -t `date +%s -d"2015-09-03 07:00"`
```

This should wake my computer tomorrow 7am right? However this is the result:

```
rtcwake: wakeup using /dev/rtc0 at Thu Sep  3 10:00:00 2015
```

10am really? I type *date* and system shows correct time but why is it setting ridiculous times here? I know this has something to do with UTC but I don't know what to do. My bios shows correct time, OS shows correct time.

Comment: Please provide the output of the command `sudo hwclock --localtime --show --debug`

Comment: `hwclock from util-linux 2.20.1
Using /dev interface to clock.
Assuming hardware clock is kept in local time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2015/09/13 19:12:41
Hw clock time : 2015/09/13 19:12:41 = 1442160761 seconds since 1969
Sun 13 Sep 2015 07:12:41 PM EEST  -0.438437 seconds`

Comment: Please check your /etc/default/rcS for UTC=no 
[to make  Linux use 'Local' time](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Make_Linux_use_.27Local.27_time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution**: As [Tuxar](https://askubuntu.com/users/175299/tuxar) shared his idea, solution is to disable [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)* (Universal Time Zone)

Let's edit this file and disable it

```
sudo nano /etc/default/rcS
```

Take a look at this screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grpsm.png
And edit the line for UTC setting, set it to UTC=no. Then ctrl+x to save, press y key to accept and press enter. At this point you might wanna logout log back in. I rebooted just in case changes are applied.
Now `rtcwake` should be using correct time zone.

**tl;dr UTC is an unnecessary invention by "scientists" to replace saying GMT.*