# How can I automate script that works? rtcwake, service network-manager

Tags: networking, scripts, suspend, cron

I have a script I want to run on regular intervals throughout the day (11:05 16:05 and 22:05. But I do not want the computer on the whole day, so I tried a script from *sudo crontab -e* suggested here.

```
0 10 * * * sudo rtcwake -m disk -l -t $(date +%s --date '11:00')
```

The thing is, it worked only if I ran it in the terminal but not from the cronjob. I also tried *sudo /usr/sbin/rtcwake xxxx* in the cronjob without luck.

But a second problem emerged when the computer woke up from the manual rtcwake-call and my script were to run. The system time was off with two hours because the system time had changed. So I had to put in a second cronjob to fix the time when the computer came to life again

```
1 11 * * * sudo hwclock -w
```

As you see it runs one minute after the computer is supposed to wake up from the first rtcwake-call putting it to sleep in the first place. I am still not sure if it works because I have not tried it yet. (The BIOS has the time 09:00 when the computer has 11:00 after the wake up)

But a third problem emerged. When I had run the rtcwakeup-call and tried to run my script manually it did not work because I had no internet connection.

So I manually did a

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and tried the script. It worked!

My question is, how do I make the thing work as a whole? The script functioned properly when the computer was on 24/7 because there were an internet connection and the time ticked along with system time and OS-time in sync.

The script runs on a Xubuntu 16 LTS computer. Perhaps it has a different setup than other distributions.

If I run sudo hwclock it says the time is 15:20 just like the clock in the corner says. But when I do the rtcwake

```
sudo rtcwake -m disk -l -t $(date +%s --date '16:25')
```

it responds that the computer will wake up at 18:25. How can both the hwclock and xubuntu clock be in sync while the timer in rtcwake is off by 2 hours? How do I sync hwclock with rtcwake? (This problem was solved with *sudo hwclock --systohc --localtime)

What is needed:

cronjob - run my script at regular intervals (collecting data from the internet)

cronjob2 - make computer go to sleep even if user or admin is not logged in

cronjob3 - when computer wakes up adjust the time so the first script (cronjob) runs at the time when it was supposed and not two hours later

cronjob4 - restart network before (cronjob) runs so that it has a fresh internet connection

Comment: Your first command likely fails because of the `%` sign - see [Unable to execute command in cron](https://askubuntu.com/a/829822/178692)

Comment: I will try that. Strange that the terminal and cronjob does not interpret it the same.

Comment: I can restart the computer at 18:25 by setting rtcwake to 16:25. I would prefer if I would not have to a two hour adjustment (which might change even more as it has changed already by two hours). Has it to do with local time?

Comment: Not sure if the proposed solution is still current (given the sysV -> upstart -> systemd transition), but possibly related: [Trying to set wake timer, date is confusing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668552/trying-to-set-wake-timer-date-is-confusing)

Comment: I fixed the timing problem with this sudo hwclock --systohc --localtime from this https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:syncing_hardware_clock_and_system_local_time    ------>>I have heard about emergent properties, but these are emergent problems. At every step of more administration weaknesses are exposed which manual commands do not show the user.

Comment: If you have found a solution, please post it as an answer so that it can help others

Comment: I have only solved part of the problem. The difference between hwclock and local time which rtcwake uses. If everything else falls into place later this afternoon I will let you know.

Comment: Please do not send this message "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" when the user does not have enough reputation to engage in a chat. ---> IF user < reputation than X then "Please do not engage in long comments" ELSE IF user > reputation than X "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions were to adjust the commands in cron

From (without backslash %s):

```
sudo rtcwake -m disk -l -t $(date +%s --date '16:25')
```

To (with backslash %s):

```
sudo rtcwake -m disk -l -t $(date +\%s --date '16:25')
```

After every awakening I also run time sync cron-job, which run approximately 3 minutes after the wake up time. During this time the OS time will jump from a lagging of two hours to the correct time. After this the hardware clock can be synchronized with the OS-time. If you sync it to fast it will sync back in time and ruin the rest of the scripts that depend on the correct time:

```
sudo hwclock --systohc --localtime
```

The latter ensures that the BIOS clock and localtime are the same. Otherwise they will drift from each other when the internal battery clock moves independently from the processor that is at rest while the computer is asleep.

To make sure the time sync works I have put both the correct time to run the cron time sync and two hours before which is the intervall my computer lags.
It means if I want the time sync to go off at 18:55 I also put in 16:55 so that it runs even if the hardware clock is out of sync with the OS clock

```
55 16,18 * * * hwclock --systohc --localtime
```

You will have to monitor your own system to see what discrepancies occur. If it moves around just put in more hours to do the sync. Perhaps even every hour. When the computer is asleep nothing will be done, but while it is awake it will sync the time every hour.

Comment: FYI the `sudo`s aren't required since you are running these from root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e`)

Comment: At this moment I would even add "magic_spell_pray_to_god_make_this_work sudo any_command && please_do_as_I_want_it_to_do"

Comment: I trust mechanical watches much more than digital. After the ordeal with these cron jobs I do definately do not trust computer time.